# Access users and groups from a console application

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to get a list of groups and users from office 365 AD from a console application.

I thought I should be able to use Microsoft Graph for this. So I tried first to fetch a token:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<hidden uuid>&client_secret=<hidden secret>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default" https://login.microsoftonline.com/testdirectory.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

I successfully receive a token here

Then I try to get a list of all the users

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <hidden bearer token>" https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

But the reply I get is

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
    "message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "<hiden-uuid>",
      "date": "2017-07-11T12:47:17"
    }
  }
}
```

It should be noted that I have a registered application at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/. I have also assigned Group.Read.All and User.Read.All permissions both as Delegated Permissions and Application Permissions. Problem is since it is a console application I guess I cannot ask the users consent. But since the application is registered at our domain account I would think it should work anyway? Or how can I give a service or console app access to the AD?

EDIT by request from @juunas here is the decoded content:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "<hidden>",
  "kid": "<hidden>"
}

{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<hidden_uuid>/",
  "iat": 1499718180,
  "nbf": 1499718180,
  "exp": 1499722080,
  "aio": "<hidden>",
  "app_displayname": "<hidden>",
  "appid": "<hidden>",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/<hidden_uuid_same_as_above>/",
  "tid": "<hidden>",
  "uti": "<hidden>",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Could you decode the access token e.g. at https://jwt.io and paste it here? Feel free to redact personal info from it of course. Anyway, it should at least contain the correct audience (MS Graph), and the correct scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically ,when building an application that uses application permissions, the app requires a page or view on which the admin approves the app's permissions. If you are building a service app , you could go to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant name}/adminconsent?client_id={application id}&state={some state data}&redirect_uri={redirect uri}`using web browser manually.

Before using this application, the tenant administrator must login and permit to use this application only once, and the login(admin consent) is needed no longer .After admin consent process , when using client credential flow to acquire token for microsoft graph api ,  if you decode the access token at [online tool](https://jwt.io/) , you could find `Group.Read.All` and `User.Read.All`application permissions in `roles` claim .

Please click [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/10/07/application-permission-with-v2-endpoint-and-microsoft-graph/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) for more details about how to use application permission with Azure AD v2 endpoint and Microsoft Graph